# Transform MongoDB Data on Find

Tags: string, function, mongodb, transform

Is it possible to transform the returned data from a Find query in MongoDB?

As an example, I have a `first` and `last` field to store a user's first and last name. In certain queries, I wish to return the first name and last initial only (e.g. 'Joe Smith' returned as 'Joe S'). In MySQL a `SUBSTRING()` function could be used on the field in the `SELECT` statement.

Are there data transformations or string functions in Mongo like there are in SQL? If so can you please provide an example of usage. If not, is there a proposed method of transforming the data aside from looping through the returned object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to do just about anything server-side with mongodb.  The reason you will usually hear "no" is you sacrifice too much speed for it to make sense under ordinary circumstances.  One of the main forces behind PyMongo, Mike Dirolf with 10gen, has a good blog post on using server-side javascript with pymongo here: http://dirolf.com/2010/04/05/stored-javascript-in-mongodb-and-pymongo.html.  His example is for storing a javascript function to return the sum of two fields.  But you could easily modify to return the first letter of your user name field.  The gist would be something like:

```
db.system_js.first_letter = "function (x) { return x.charAt(0); }"
```

Understand first, though, that mongodb is made to be really good at retrieving your data, not really good at processing it.  The recommendation (see for example 50 tips and tricks for mongodb developers from Kristina Chodorow by Oreilly) is to do what Andrew tersely alluded to doing above: make a first letter column and return that instead.  Any processing can be more efficiently done in the application.

But if you feel that even querying for the fullname before returning fullname[0] from your 'view' is too much of a security risk, you don't need to do everything the fastest possible way.  I'd avoided map-reduce in mongodb for awhile because of all the public concerns about speed.  Then I ran my first map reduce and twiddled my thumbs for .1 seconds as it processed 80,000 10k documents.  I realize in the scheme of things, that's tiny.  But it illustrates that just because it's bad for a massive website to take a performance hit on some server side processing, doesn't mean it would matter to you.  In my case, I imagine it would take me slightly longer to migrate to Hadoop than to just eat that .1 seconds every now and then.  Good luck with your site

Comment: Additionally, I've found using MongooseJS I can accomplish this using a "virtual". Such as: schUsers.virtual('lastInitial').get(function(){ return this.last.substr(0,1);}); I'm unsure what this translates to as MongoDb Code, or if its wholly processed by Mongoose.

Comment: Dirolf's blog post doesn't answer the question.  He's using a function in the "where" part of the query, not the projection.  I came to this question because I wanted to know how to call a function in the project, just like OP's example of returning "Joe S".  I still don't know how to do that, or even if it's possible without adding a new column to the collection.

Answer (score 0):

The question you should ask yourself is why you need that data. If you need it for display purposes, do that in your view code. If you need it for query purposes, then do as Andrew suggested, and store it as an extra field on the object. Mongo doesn't provide server-side transformations (usually, and where it does, you usually don't want to use them); the answer is usually to not treat your data as you would in a relational DB, but to use the more flexible nature of the data store to pre-bake your data into the formats that you're going to be using.

If you can provide more information on how this data should be used, then we might be able to answer a little more usefully.

Comment: The data set is used for a web service. Depending on the requestor's permissions, they made not have access to viewing a user's full last name, and in that scenario, just the first initial is returned. This, obviously, does not allow for transformation on the view layer. I could create another field, but it seems silly as I don't need to query against such a field.

Comment: Why can't you do it on the view? That seems like the right place to be deciding what to render based on the viewing user's permissions.