# mongodb aggregate with temporary field

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo collections as

**books**

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId('5a1d21044e0ae92f7455f651'),
  "author": "5a1d2629271a75167c15d284",
  "name": "Grafta"
}
```

**author**

```
{
  "_id": "ObjectId('5a1d2629271a75167c15d284')",
  "name": "Anto"
}
```

How can I use the aggregate with `books.author` and `author._id`?

Tried using the `$addFields` in aggregate

```
db.getCollection('books').aggregate([

  {
      $addFields:{aId: ObjectId("$author")},
  },

  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "author",
      localField: "aId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "authorDetails"
    }
  }
])
```

and it throws error

```
Failed to execute script.

Error: invalid object id: length :
@(shell):4:24
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ObjectId` constructor does not evaluate in the aggregation pipeline but right away, with `$author` as its argument, which is causing the error.

Although there is at least [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8105599/3082668)  describing how to transform data in queries, I think the correct thing to do, if possible, is to fix the schema by making `$author` a proper `ObjectId`.